# How to unlink material from a mesh, with python script?

Tags: materials, python, scripting

Blender 2.68a, Python 3.3

I would like to unlink material from a mesh, and even after googling a hour I don't know how to do it. I only saw scripts that work in Blender 2.5x only for this.

So could someone tell me (or link info), how to do this:

[image]

with python script?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## Unlink a Material

Remove the first material from the mesh.

```
import bpy
obj = bpy.context.object
obj.data.materials.pop(0, update_data=True)
```

Remove all materials.

```
import bpy
obj = bpy.context.object
obj.data.materials.clear()
```

## Unlink Texface

This clears images for each face (active uv layer only)

```
import bpy
obj = bpy.context.object
for tf in obj.data.uv_textures.active.data:
    tf.image = None
```

This clears images for **all** UV layers

```
import bpy
obj = bpy.context.object
for texlay in obj.data.uv_textures:
    for tf in texlay.data:
        tf.image = None
```

---

Update: [TexFace has been removed in Blender2.8](https://developer.blender.org/T51382)

Comment: Trying to avoid comments, like "thanks"... LOL but thanks, I would never thought it is the "pop" I was looking for. Will accept in 2 mins, and vote up when I get 15 repu.

Comment: Ideally we would be able to do: `del obdata.materials[0]`, Which would be the most obvious way to do this, but this way doesn't accept arguments for how to handle linked data.

Comment: Is there something similar for textures?

Comment: @McLawrence best ask a new question, link to this one.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do the following to properly remove materials. This will both unlink the materials and also remove the unlinked materials from memory. [ideasman42](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/55/ideasman42)'s original solution does not remove the left-over data blocks and can cause [memory leakage](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102025/how-to-prevent-memory-leakage-in-blender) issues unless you close/re-open Blender or exit the current Python environment (the`multiprocessing` package can help with the latter). Here's a modified version of the solution that [ideasman42](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/55/ideasman42) proposed that properly removes materials:

```
import bpy
obj = bpy.context.scene.objects.active
mats = obj.data.materials

for mat in mats:
    mat.user_clear()

matLength = len(mats)
for i in range(matLength):
    obj.data.materials.pop(0, update_data=True)

leftOverMatBlocks = [block for block in bpy.data.materials if block.users == 0]
for block in leftOverMatBlocks:
    bpy.data.materials.remove(block)
bpy.context.scene.update()

mats.clear() # I'd recommend not executing this line. It might sometimes cause the object not be shown in final rendering
```