# Prevent Blender to add numbers behind materials when importing a FBX

Tags: materials, import

is it possible that Blender don't add numbers behind the materials when I import a FBX? 
Because right now I have the problem, that I have to change the material for every window in the scene.

For example, the normal Name for Glas.120 should only be Glas.

Thanks for your help.

[image]

Comment: To clarify, it's not adding number to name, it's adding a new material each time.  Just like objects, if you add a new one with same name, it gets number extension.  There was a post recently on consolidating all materials to one, "xxx.nnn" -> "xxx".  [remove duplicate materials](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55233/disable-material-duplication)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully, using a **Material Specials** addon could do the job for you:

1. Enable it in *User Preferences* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>) > *Addons*.

   [image]
2. After you import your model, use the slots menu by clicking the arrow down button (beside material slots list) and navigate to *Specials > Merge Base Names*

   [image]
3. Set *AutoRename* and click OK, it should remove .00X from all materials (not only for selected object)

   [image]

   If you get multiple materials with the same name, you can try *Clean Material Slots* function:

   [image]

Comment: this is not supported in the latest version (3.0.1)

Answer (score 2):

To clarify, it's not adding number to name, it's adding a new material each time. Just like objects, if you add a new one with same name, it gets number extension.

As an alternative, for those that don't wish to use material specials addon, a simple little cleaner script.

To elaborate on the answer to consolidating all materials to one, "xxx.nnn" -> "xxx". in [disable material duplication](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55233/disable-material-duplication)

after you have imported an FBX all imported objects are in the `context.selected_objects` collection.  Not all of these will  have materials.  A more brute strength approach would be using the `scene.objects` collection, which is all objects in scene.

Code from [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/55247/15543) modified to be run directly after import, that is while the newly imported objects are selected.  Copy script and paste in text block, then run script to remove dupe materials only from the objects newly imported..

```
import bpy
context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene
mats = bpy.data.materials

for obj in context.selected_objects: # selected context.scene.objects:
    # all objects have material_slots
    for slot in obj.material_slots:
        part = slot.name.rpartition('.')
        mat =  mats.get(part[0])
        if part[2].isnumeric() and mat is not None:
            slot.material = mat
```