# Changing a material's name with Python

Tags: materials

I can do a LOT of things with Python in Blender, but for some reason I'm struggling with changing the material name.

When I import an FBX Blender renames the material names if they are dupes.  So I get a "Glass.001", "Glass.002" but I really need them to all just be "Glass".  I can rename them manually with no problems, but my code to do so fails.

```
for obj in bpy.data.objects:
    for num, m in list(enumerate(obj.material_slots)): #rename materials with . numbers
        if m.material:
            myhold = m.material.name        
            if myhold.find(".") > -1:
                print ("Material is", m.material.name)
                tempholder = myhold[:myhold.find(".")]
                m.material.name = tempholder
                print ("Material is now", tempholder)
                print ("So should be", m.material.name)
```

which prints something like:

"Material is Glass.001"
"Material is now Glass"
"So should be Glass.001"

It must be something obvious but I don't get it.  TIA for any help.

Answer (score 1):

**Each material has a unique name**

Each ID object in blender has a unique name. Internally blender does this for us if needed. Eg duplicate the cube. This is often referred to as the "naming system".

For example, If another material already has the name you are trying to assign, to test `bpy.materials.get("Glass") is not None` then cannot name another material "Glass". Can try to, `anothermaterial.name = "Glass", but the naming system will rename it with a .nnn extension.

This explains the behaviour described in your question.

> I can rename them manually with no problems

Seriously doubt that claim. Contend that instead you are also unwittingly renaming the original. (or selecting it from material drop down)

[image]
*Rename green material to "Material" just like blue*

If you want to link to only one;  assign the material to the "Glass" original, eg using the `tempholder` name from script above

```
m.material = bpy.data.materials.get(tempholder)
```

[image]
*Assigning each slot linked to  "Material.nnn" to "Material"*

[Prevent Blender to add numbers behind materials when importing a FBX](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91378/prevent-blender-to-add-numbers-behind-materials-when-importing-a-fbx)

[Disable Material Duplication](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55233/disable-material-duplication)

Comment: Okay, I guess I'll have to hit it on the backside of what I'm doing (which is creating folders for those material names -- I can rename them.