# Add functionality to existing commands

Tags: scripting, import

I want to update my import .fbx, so it would replace and remove all duplicate materials. I have found how to do the action at: [link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/91387/71697)

However, I don't really want to create my whole custom import .fbx that would basically do the same thing as the regular import, but also execute this at the end.

Is there a way I could piggyback my custom code onto existing functions? Meaning my addon script would only be:

```
def at_import_fbx_end():
    do_my_stuff()
```

Or something similar to this.

Comment: Is it possible to locate and reuse Blender's own code for importing FBX files? It's all open source and - with UI elements at least - it's often quite easy to find the source code for it. EDIT: I've found something that might help so I'll write an answer.

Comment: Great suggestion. I was able to locate the files, and this will make the whole ordeal easier, and it will work, but it will be a separate import. Checking the code, I wasn't able to locate a function called, or event, or something, so I don't think I can just piggyback off of it

Comment: You can override operators to add logic before or after calling it. It's a bit hacky but could work

Comment: You mean directly editing the source code to include my custom decorator? I don't see any other way to do this, and I would very much like to avoid editing source code, as that's not really ideal, I'd rather just make the new import button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can piggyback on an operator by declaring another operator that uses the same `bl_idname`. It's a common gotcha that we can use to our advantage. It's a hack and it might mess up things when you unregister, but nothing that you can't repair in a few minutes by replacing the script files.

This script will for instance apply a translation to all imported objects :

```
import bpy
from bpy_extras.io_utils import ImportHelper

import io_scene_fbx


class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator, ImportHelper):
    bl_idname = "import_scene.fbx"  # Overwrite the base operator
    bl_label = "FBX override"

    def execute(self, context):
        # You can do things before importing
        io_scene_fbx.ImportFBX.execute(self, context)
        # You can do things after importing
        bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(0, 0, 5))
        return {"FINISHED"}

# We steal the importer settings. However the display will be messed up :
SimpleOperator.__annotations__.update(io_scene_fbx.ImportFBX.__annotations__)  

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleOperator)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleOperator)
    bpy.utils.register_class(io_scene_fbx.ImportFBX)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: LEGEN-dary. Exactly what I asked for, thank you. Any chance I can also add custom stuff to the existing import panel? `BoopProperty` to turn on or off this extra custom stuff?

Comment: And yes, when I was messing up with the original `io_import_fbx`, after unregistering it, I had to re-register the included `FBX` for it to work again.

Comment: Did some testing, and while I was able to add the check box into the import settings, I wasn't able to ignore it later on - it always got passed as keyword, and since it was extra, it threw an error

Comment: You can add properties to the operator and they will be displayed and work as they would normally. But In this case I couldn't do it specifically because of this line https://github.com/blender/blender-addons/blob/master/io_scene_fbx/__init__.py#L216 which dumbly relies on an exact sequence of argument names... https://github.com/blender/blender-addons/blob/master/io_scene_fbx/import_fbx.py#L2348-L2368 because when you add a property to the operator, it will also be added to `self.as_keywords` dictionary

Comment: One solution is to change this line in your blender install folder's scripts https://github.com/blender/blender-addons/blob/master/io_scene_fbx/__init__.py#L206-L207 and add your property name(s) to the list. I didn't test  but I assume it would stop throwing errors

Comment: Yes, I assume that would solve the issue, but I'd rather avoid that, since it's not just for me.

Comment: You can also completely copy/paste the `execute` in your operator and fix the error there. You'd have to redo it if the base code ever changed if you want to be up to date. And you'd need to `from io_scene_fbx.import_fbx import load`

Comment: At this moment, I could just completely copy paste the import part inside `io_import_fbx`, replace parts I like, and it would not break the menu as well. I think we've reached the end here, with multiple options and some tradeoffs. Thanks for your contribution

Comment: Happy to help ! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I just had a quick look and if you right click on any menu operator you can access certain shortcuts, including the Python command for it. See image:
[image: as described]

(To enable this function, you need to enable Python tooltips in Interface preferences > Display > Python Tooltips)

So for this example, your script could start with `bpy.ops.import_scene.fbx()`, then you add `do_my_stuff()` afterwards. (I clicked the copy command from the shown UI button for that code)

It may be that in order to combine these in a way that works, you'll need to add a custom UI panel or something where you can choose which file to import and then let your code run, removing duplicate materials once you've imported it.

As far as I know, Blender does not contain any signals for finishing things like file imports or other processes.

Comment: (To enable this function, you need to enable Python tooltips in Interface preferences)

Comment: Thanks, I'll add that as a quick disclaimer just in case!

Comment: Just using the `bpy.ops.import_scene.fbx()` doesn't help much, as that's importing the files on your own. The issues is, that the existing importer already has plenty of presets, but is missing some (in this case, the duplicate materials).

That means I still have to copy the whole code of the import (as I want to keep all the possible import settings), and add my stuff on top of that.
https://github.com/blender/blender-addons/blob/master/io_scene_fbx/__init__.py