# Reducing Material duplicates in .obj export to Unity

Tags: texturing, materials, unity

I'm trying to reduce the amount of materials exported from Blender, in my .obj into Unity.
My house mesh has 11 textures/materials. When I export it as an .obj and import it into Unity, it currently appears with 21 material slots. This seems to gradually increase.

I have looked at the Blender manual pages:
https://www.blender.org/manual//render/blender_render/materials/material_panel.html
...and googled and just tried to play with the Material and Texure panels in the Object Properties panel, but I cannot get a grip on how these panels relate to one another.
I have gone through every object in the project and made sure each material of a given type is pointing to the same material. I have tried selecting textures that are duplicates and shift-clicking the 'X' by their name to allegedly remove them from the project.

But there are still excess Materials when I save the Blender project, re-load and export to Unity.

Could someone please explain how the Texture panel in Object Properties actually works? How does changing the settings in there affect the Material? Are these global changes I'm making, or does the Texture panel only affect the selected Material? Is there even a selected Material?

I can't make it make sense! If someone has found a page that explains this clearly, that would be great.

Any help much appreciated!

**EDIT**

After having spent a few more hours trying to understand this, I have a clearer idea of what doesn't make sense to me: It's the three sub-tabs on the Texture tab that I don't understand ('Show world textures', 'Show material textures' and 'Show other data textures'). What do these tabs DO? Any way I manipulate them has no effect on the excess materials and I'm particularly struggling to fathom the 'world' and 'other' tabs.
Once again, if anyone wants to put me out my misery, that would be great (I will, of course, continue the research...)

Comment: Please follow the instructions here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5300/how-can-i-remove-all-unused-materials-from-a-file . You can also export to fbx.

Comment: I have seen that question before (and this one ... http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/100/how-do-i-completely-remove-an-image-from-my-blend-file ) and, as I said above, I have 'unlinked' the spurious materials, saved and reloaded, but the excess materials remain in Unity. Unless I'm not 'unlinking' the materials correctly. Do you have any more detailed information than the answer you link to on how to do that?

Comment: *Show world textures* shows textures available for environment (it can be procedural sky or hdri map). *Show other data* shows textures used for anything else like sculpt or texture paint brushes, images used in modifiers etc. And only *Show material texture* will show you textures linked to material and available for exporting (so that's your point of interest). I don't quite get how could that be related here. The double materials should've been deleted if you made them 0-users, saved+reloaded file.