# Material saving issue during "Seperate by Material"

Tags: materials

During my workflow I am joining meshes together and then using "Separate by Material" and vice-versa. During this process, sometimes the materials are not saved. I posted about it in this thread:
[Material names missing](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66114/material-names-missing)

I now uploaded a Blender file to Blend-Exchange to show the issue.
[image]
Here are the steps to reproduce what is happening:

1. Open the Blender file
2. Notice Mesh1 and Mesh2 have material slots and materials
3. Join Mesh1 with Mesh2
4. Go into edit mode, and select everything in the joined mesh and do
   "Separate by Material"
5. Save the blender file
6. Re-open the Blender file and notice the material slots are there,
   but the Materials are now "missing", as shown in the linked question

So why might this be happening?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this, it's not happening here. What version of Blender are you using?

Comment: Using 2.77a  Date:2016-04-05  18:12   Hash:abf6408   Windows 10

Comment: I just looked at the bug reports and this seems to be listed as some type of bug. https://developer.blender.org/T49228     [RC2] Fix T49228: Separate by material, materials disappear after reload (rBab934e7d61).  It sounds like the same issue I'm having. I'm going to try to download 2.78 and see if the issue still happens

Comment: This was a known bug in 2.77a.
https://developer.blender.org/T49228

I now installed Blender 2.78a and the issue is resolved by using the new version of Blender. The material is now saved and loaded correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a known bug in 2.77a.
https://developer.blender.org/T49228

I now installed Blender 2.78a and the issue is resolved by using the new version of Blender. The material is now saved and loaded correctly.