# How do I clear this list so I can start empty and fresh?

Tags: materials

Pretty much this.  I'm a bit stuck on getting a decent bake my first time and want to clear the slate and start fresh.  [image]

Comment: The 0 next to the material indicates it has no users, aka an orphan.  Putting  the outliner in "Orphan Data" mode and hitting the purge button will remove all but _Material.003_

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5300/how-can-i-remove-all-unused-materials-from-a-blend-file

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is a way to clear this list without a script. If you don't want to use a script, save your objects individually, and re-load the Blender start-up file. Then import your objects, and make new shaders.

Answer (score 0):

Select the material you want to remove and press the little X to the right of it